# Vba runtime error: 91

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word, runtime-error

I am trying to send email using Outlook to every email address in `column:A` in an Excel sheet and insert a Word document in the body. I have written the following code but it gives me run-time error 91. I am using Office 2013.

```
Public Sub Create_Outlook_Email()

Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, OutWordEditor As Object
Dim WordDoc As Object
Dim wordfile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

 'Create new Outlook email
Set rng = Range("a2:a50")
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set OutWordEditor = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

For Each row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells

        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Your emails are moving on " & Range("e2").Value & "- don't get left behind     "

            wordfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select MS Word file", MultiSelect:=False)
            Set WordDoc = GetObject(wordfile)
            WordDoc.Content.Copy
            WordDoc.Close
            OutWordEditor.Content.Paste

            'See if Outlook is using Word to edit messages

            .display
            .send
        End With

        Set OutApp = Nothing
        Set OutMail = Nothing

        Set OutWordEditor = Nothing
        Set WordDoc = Nothing

    Next cell
Next row  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to help if you provided information about the line where the error occurs. For instance you have the following error, it is very likely that it is the source of your problem:

> ```
> Set OutWordEditor = Nothing
> ```

You are doing this inside the loop, but then you dont set the `OutWordEditor` variable in the next iteration. Hence you get "object not set" at the second iteration, at the line `OutWordEditor.Content.Paste`.

The solution I suggest is that you move these statements to **inside the loop**:

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set OutWordEditor = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
```

Besides, you dont need two nested loops, just one:

> ```
> For Each row In rng.Rows
> For Each cell In row.Cells
> ...
> Next
> Next
> ```

With all the above, your (single loop) becomes like this:

```
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If Len(Trim(cell.Value)) = 0 Then Exit For ' <-- to stop at emty cell
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set OutWordEditor = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    ... 'Rest of the loop
Next
```

Comment: @YowE3K IIRC we had a discussion about that in the past :) this way of opening a word or excel file is also correct; the appropriate application is found in the registry.

Comment: Nope - no discussion with me about that.  (None that I **remember** anyway.)  But I will believe you.

Comment: @YowE3K That was probably not with you, I dont remember exactly, but I'm pretty sure that was in the early days we "met" each other :P

Comment: Oooh - look at that (I just tried it out) - I learnt something new again!!!  Thanks

Comment: I can't remember things I discussed yesterday, so certainly won't remember things from the "early days" :D

Comment: Notice this syntax is handy and short (cool), I must say. Waiting to see its drawbacks, there might be some but didn't find them yet. Notice that you can still retrieve the parent application if needed, using `workbook.Parent`, `Document.Parent` etc..

Comment: Will probably confuse things when some user changes the default application for an extension and therefore all the object properties don't work - that will make for some interesting trouble-shooting! ("Do you have your default application for `.docx` files set to Microsoft Word" is not one of the first things I would think of asking if a user said that the code crashed on `WordDoc.Content.Copy` :D)  Luckily most people don't change the default applications.

Comment: @YowE3K yeah, but it might happen (i.e. open-office?). I think you caught the main drawback. Robust code should not allow for such anomalies. thumbs up.

Comment: @A.S.H it works great aftre your suggestion . How ever the macro doesn't stop whell there is a empty cell in the range . Can you please help with this?

Comment: @GT0028 what do you want to do when the cell is empty: skip the cell, or stop the whole thing?

Comment: @A.S.H      stop the whole thing . May be with a message like " All Done".

Comment: @GT0028 see the added line after the `For Each`.